# Filter an array by number?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've got an array with a list of numbers, e.g.

```
[10, 30, 50, 54, 56, 95, 97, 99]
```

If I provide a number e.g. 52, it needs to return the next lowest number in the array, in this case that would be 50.

**What's the cleanest way to do this?**

Please state if the array must be sorted first.

Comment: Another way, that's quite efficient though a bit homely: `n = [10, 54, 50, 30].min_by { |e| (e < 52) ? 52-e : 61 }; n = nil if n==61 #=> 50`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd go for something like this (no need for sorting):

```
[10, 30, 50, 54, 56, 95, 97, 99].select {|n| n < 52}.max
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can work for a sorted array:

```
[10, 30, 50, 54, 56, 95, 97, 99].sort.reverse.find { |el| el < number }
```

It simply changes the sorting direction to descending and finds first smaller element

Comment: Think showing `sort` call would add value: `[10, 30, 50, 54, 56, 95, 97, 99].sort.reverse.find { |el| el < number }`

Comment: Sorting is expensive. In general, if you only want a largest or smallest value, don't sort.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with a sorted array is to use [`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) on its reverse:

```
[10, 30, 50, 54, 56, 95, 97, 99].reverse.bsearch { |n| n < 52 } # => 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Use detect instead of select because select iterate through all your elements. detect returns the first occurrence that matched.

The array doesn't have to be sorted.

```
[10, 30, 50, 54, 56, 95, 97, 99].sort { |a, b| b <=> a }.detect { |v| v <= 52 }
```

Comment: The array has to be sorted. You even sort it in your answer!

Comment: yes, it's what I'm saying. The input array doesn't have to be sorted, because the line I wrote sort it before returning the lowest value. but I don't iterate through all of the array because of the detect.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the array is sorted:

```
ary = [...]
pivot = 52
ary.partition{|n| n < pivot}[0][-1]
```

Comment: `ary.partition{|n| n < pivot}[0]` is the same as `ary.select { |n| n < pivot }`, which is more direct. What if the array is not sorted? You don't want to sort to find just one value, so you are led to nesiseka's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must try [rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-rindex)

```
ary.sort.rindex {|el| el < number}
```

and that return the first matching element.